# I converted py file to an exe file (pyinstaller) i used a print statement before input but while running the exe file it doesnt print and takes input

Tags: python, pyinstaller

[snippet of exe file after opening and entering a number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLitF.png)

After opening .exe file it shows a blinking cursor but it has to print 'enter a number' according to the code, but after I enter any number it prints the statement along with the number I entered... Is there any way to print that statement before entering value?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should give us: a minimal Python code reproducing the problem, and the exact way you convert it to use (the pyinstaller command line and optional config files). Without that we cannot guess what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `input()`?

```
def check():
    d = int(input("Guess the number: "))
```

I assume you're using Python 3, if you're using Python 2 you need to use `raw_input()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer  but I instead used sys.std.readline() and it works like a charm